# FCM отправка запроса для несколькольких пользователей с разными данными одновременно

Tags: php, уведомления, fcm

Как можно отправить уведомление через `FCM` за раз для несколькольких пользователей, но при этом для каждого прописать отдельную дату?

Я на сервере поставил крон на каждые 2 секунды, и каждый раз скрипт получает список неотправленных уведомлений с датами и отправляет их. Но в данный момент это осуществляется так: `один запрос = одно уведомление`, что не очень хорошо, когда их бывает 500 штук и сервер отправляет 500 запросов один за другим.

Answer (score 5):

Замените: `"to": "YOUR-TOKEN-ID"`

На:
`"registration_ids": [
    "YOUR-TOKEN-ID-1",
    "YOUR-TOKEN-ID-2"
    "YOUR-TOKEN-ID-3"
  ]`

Таким способом можно отправлять до 1000 получателям за раз.

Comment: в этом случае дата для всех токенов будет одинаково. Мне надо чтобы каждый юзер получал индивидуальную дату